# copying row 3 in a bunch of .csv files to a meta file

Tags: python, csv

For this project I have a folder named "Files" and within this folder I have one hundred folders labeled 1 to 100. In each folder, 1 to 100, there is a single .csv file named "data1.csv" and there are the same 3 rows in each data1.csv in all 1-100 folders with comma delimited text (with some variation of data of course)

I want to have my python script:
1. take all the text in comma-delimited format in row 3 in each data1.csv in each 1-100 folder and dump it into a master .csv file.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far... Some things you might want to look into are `xlrd` and `xlwt`...

Answer (score 0):

how to walk a directory (os.walk)

http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html

to open a file, it is considered best practice to do

```
with open(filename,'r') as fin:
```

which 'wraps' the file handler and closes it outside the block, this is opposed to old style

```
fin = open(filename,'r')
fin.readline()
fin.close()
```

python has lists

```
lst = []
```

you will want to use the example for walking a directory tree, and grab the full file paths

simply loop over all the files, read them in using

```
result = fin.readline() #3x or
result = fin.readlines()[2]
```

finally append the results to your lst

```
lst.append(result)
```

and at the very end, dump it into a file via the following cmd

```
with open(outfilename,'w') as fout:
    fout.write( '\n'.join(lst) )
```